# Flutter app restoration; how to save the app state when the activity is killed by the system?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm an android developer and I want to switch to flutter. I love the hot reload feature that allows for faster development time. The only thing that prevents me from switching so far is that flutter lacks the option to save the app state when the activity is killed. In native android the option is provided for free (`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`). So my question is,  how can I implement the same feature in Flutter?

Comment: You want to save the state of any activity when the activity is killed. You talk about app state.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beginning with Flutter 1.22 (which is now in stable), you can make use of `RestorationMixin`. Here's a full example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    RootRestorationScope(
      restorationId: 'root',
      child: MaterialApp(home: HomePage()),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with RestorationMixin {
  final RestorableInt _counter = RestorableInt(0);

  @override
  String get restorationId => 'HomePage';

  @override
  void restoreState(RestorationBucket oldBucket, bool initialRestore) {
    registerForRestoration(_counter, 'counter');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _counter.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('${_counter.value}'),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => ++_counter.value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

#### How to test:

- Go to your device Settings - Developer Options and turn on `Don't keep activities`.

[image]

- Now run the app on your Android device, tap the Counters button and hit the home button to force Android to exit your app.
- Open the app again and you should see the `counter` value persist.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working at all. Will it save the state between developer hot restarts?

Comment: @LukePighetti It saves the state when the app is killed by the Android system. Please see how to test section.

Comment: This doesn't work on any other operating systems?

Comment: @LukePighetti No, it only works on Android.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a plugin and method channels in order to know when to persist things, and when to restore things. For that, you can use the following library:

https://github.com/littlerobots/flutter-native-state

It lets you send your state into a Bundle on the Android side, and communicates restored state back to Flutter through method channel.

Comment: You can actually use the new RestorableMixin now, so this answer is out of date.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @CopsOnRoad, points below are related to his answer.

1. We should use **RootRestorationScope** instead of **RestorationScope**

like this...

```
void main() {
      runApp(
          RootRestorationScope( // <--fix
          restorationId: 'root',
          child: MaterialApp(home: HomePage()),
        ),
      );
    }
```

2. also RestorationMixin has generic: RestorationMixin<**HomePage**> - not necessary, but if you want to declare your HomeRestorationMixin later, and if you want to make correct signature in *didUpdateWidget(HomePage widget)* method...
3. also we should manually run dispose() for every property of the State:

so it will be

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with 
  RestorationMixin<HomePage> { // <-- optional
  ...
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _counter.dispose(); // <-- recommended
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone wondering why the solution from [@CopsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183856/17286537) didn't works. You need to add the restorationScopeId in MaterialApp.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    RootRestorationScope(
      restorationId: 'root',
      child: MaterialApp(
        restorationScopeId: 'app', // <-- add this line
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html), only usable with the `didChangeAppLifecycleState method`, that you can use to handle the [`AppLifecycleState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html).