# Flutter RootRestorationScope not restoring last root

Tags: flutter, dart, state, root

I was using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/last_state, but when i update to flutter 1.22 a new feature came out `RootRestorationScope` that seems could replace that external plugin, but after testing it and following some tutos ([tuto1](https://dev.to/pedromassango/what-is-state-restoration-and-how-to-use-it-in-flutter-5blm), [tuto2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040827/how-to-save-the-app-state-in-flutter-when-the-activity-is-killed-by-the-system)) i noticed that it restore the state but it does not restore the route ! am i missing something ?
there is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  RootRestorationScope( // Register a restoration scope for the entire app!
    restorationId: 'root',
    child: MyApp(),
  ),
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DummyPage(),
    );
  }
}

class DummyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const route = "/intermediate";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Another page'),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Onwards"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: false).push(
            MaterialPageRoute<bool>(
              fullscreenDialog: true,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

// Our state should be mixed-in with RestorationMixin
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with RestorationMixin {

  // For each state, we need to use a restorable property
  final RestorableInt _index = RestorableInt(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RestorationScope(
      restorationId: 'tess',
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text('Index is ${_index.value}')),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _index.value,
          onTap: (i) => setState(() => _index.value = i),
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home'
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                label: 'Notifications'
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                label: 'Settings'
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // The restoration bucket id for this page,
  // let's give it the name of our page!
  String get restorationId => 'home_page';

  @override
  void restoreState(RestorationBucket oldBucket, bool initialRestore) {
    // Register our property to be saved every time it changes,
    // and to be restored every time our app is killed by the OS!
    registerForRestoration(_index, 'nav_bar_index');
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 2):

use `restorablePush` rather than `push` and give every route an restorationId

> Routes added with the classic imperative API (push, pushNamed, and
> friends) can never restore their state. A Route added with the
> restorable imperative API (restorablePush, restorablePushNamed, and
> all other imperative methods with "restorable" in their name) restores
> its state if all routes below it up to and including the first
> Page-based route below it are restored. If there is no Page-based
> route below it, it only restores its state if all routes below it
> restore theirs.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html