# Flutter: Executing a Task after App is Killed

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I would like to execute some asynchronous code just before my Flutter App is killed by the OS due to low memory.

I am currently using the WidgetsBindingObserver mixin to listen to app lifecycle changes, and when the app is paused (before it is detached) start the code execution.

The code I'm trying to execute:
I am trying to commit something to a local cache using SharedPreferences, but to no avail. It doesn't end up committing the data.

The Potential Issues:
I'm not sure if it is primarily due to running code while the app is being detached - in which case it could be solved by using the WorkManager package.
Or, if it is related to accessing Shared Preferences after the app has already been detached.

Any help or insight would be welcome!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183856/15117201

Comment: Unfortunately not. I need to restore a fair amount of data from many (35 - 150) user inputs throughout the process. I'm exploring committing the data to a Hive DB to create a local data store to restore from.

Comment: Honestly, I would consider to store each input after your form swiches the focus to another input field. You could store this temorarily and once the entire form is validated and submitted store the data as intended. Then you could pre-populate the form, if the user decides to complete it at another time - could improve UX.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jahn! I've decided to do something like this. This issue was more related to deciding when to do the local form data save. I am now saving the form data locally when a field is completed/shifted focus, and reloading and pre-populating the form when they come back to it.

Comment: You´re welcome but that is what I recommended, switching focus is basically completing the field ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the WidgetsBindingObserver mixin doesn't work for my use-case. When the lifecycle status changes to detached, any asynchronous code executed after this is not able to complete in time.

I solved the problem using a local key-pair store called Hive to locally save the form data as it was inputted by the user. Then, when they are ready to resume the form completion, re-populate the form and allow them to continue filling it out.