# Flutter keep current screen on resume

Tags: android, flutter

In my app I have multiple screens, like: `Login`, `Home` and `2ndScreen`. If I go to `2ndScreen`, then minimize app and then open it again, it shows Home screen instead of 2ndScreen.
So my question is: How can I keep current app screen after app resume?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the app state restoration.

You can use `RestorationManager` which is the class that is responsible for handling all the state restoration work.

Below articles can help you to get started with it.

[Introduction to State Restoration in Flutter](https://dev.to/pedromassango/what-is-state-restoration-and-how-to-use-it-in-flutter-5blm)

[Flutter State restoration | Restore Scrollviews and Textfields](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-state-restoration-restore-scrollviews-and-textfields-d1d35cbd878c)

**EDIT**

There's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183856/7652758) for a similar question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will take a look.