# Flutter restoration doesn't restore nor save state?

Tags: android, flutter

Been looking into restoring previous application state in-case the application closes but the problem I'm having is that the values do not get restored.

I've tried copying and pasting the example for [RestorationMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorationMixin-mixin.html#widgets.RestorationMixin.1) on the official API page but it still doesn't restore it's value.

I've also followed [@CopsOnRoad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183856/21090879) steps on how to test it but the results are the same.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I just got it works. From the official API, you need to add this:

```
void main() => runApp(const RootRestorationScope(// <-- this
  restorationId: 'root', // <-- and give the resorationId
  child: RestorationExampleApp(),
));
```